# Newbie question on restricted boltzmann machine

Tags: machine-learning, rbm

I’m quite a newbie to RBMs so I’m trying to understand how do you feed real valued data to it given that all the visible and hidden units are binary?

Comment: This might help: https://medium.com/@neuralnets/boltzmann-machines-transformation-of-unsupervised-deep-learning-part-1-42659a74f530

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an answer which might help: https://www.quora.com/What-are-best-approaches-to-modeling-real-value-continuous-input-variables-in-RBM-pretraining